# Three.js: 'up' in Mesh object

Tags: three.js

While debugging three.js code, I see following member in a mesh instance(made from THREE.PlaneGeometry):

```
up
:
THREE.Vector3
x
:
0
y
:
1
z
:
0
```

What does 'up' signify?

And, if I rotate the mesh by:

```
rotation.set(Math.PI/2, 0, 0);
```

Would it impact 'up' too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does 'up' signify?

Just have a look at the [official documentation](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/core/Object3D.up). It is used by `lookAt()` in order to calculate an orientation of a 3D object.

> Would it impact 'up' too?

No.